# rangeSlider not working , in Jquery mobile at change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using the RangeSlider widget of jQuery mobile.

### HTML

```
<form id="rangeSliderForm"> <span class="minValueRange"> 0 </span> **************** <span class="maxValueRange"></span>

    <div id="range-slider" data-role="rangeslider">
        <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="40" type="range">
        <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="80" type="range">
    </div>
</form>
```

Then I am changing the values and setting the max and min values dynamically. First time it works fine. But the second time, when I change page and come back, the handler to drag is not working

```
$("div#range-slider").rangeslider();
$("#range-1a").val(0);
$("#range1b").val(10000);
$("#range-1a").attr("max", parseInt(10000);
$("#range-1b").attr("max", 10000);
$("div#range-slider").rangeslider('refresh');
```

Please share your thoughts...

Comment: what does your console say?

Comment: @madalinivascu: no errors

Comment: when you refresh the page the code presented doesn't execute?

Comment: @madalinivascu:its executing, even if i didnt, put the code, and go with the html only, at this scenario also its not working

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve with these sliders?

Comment: i want those sliders to work even after the changepage

Comment: why didn't you say so, you will need to save the state of the slider in a cookie/localstorage/sessionstorage

Comment: okay.. i'll check... and update you...

Answer (score 0):

You should not re-initialize the widget on each pagechange. So remove the line:

```
$("div#range-slider").rangeslider();
```

jQM already has initialized the widget, you just need the refresh call after setting the values.

Handle the pagebeforeshow event on the page with the rangeslider:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page1", function () {    
    $("#range-1a").val(10);
    $("#range-1b").val(10000);
    $("#range-1a").prop("max", 10000);
    $("#range-1b").prop("max", 10000);
    $("#range-slider").rangeslider('refresh');    
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3190am26/)**